# Infura and Remix Smart Contract

Tags: remix, infura

I have a smart contract in Remix and would like to be able to filter events using Infura. I know nothing on how to get started. I went to infura and created a project which has a project ID. What should I do next? How do I connect them together?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the solution as a whole (event filtering), but I can help by connecting to Infura from Remix:

1. Open "DEPLOY & RUN TRANSACTIONS" tab from the left panel (Eth logo and ">")
2. In the "Environment" field choose "Web3 Provider"
3. In the opened pop-up window put your Infura endpoint. Endpoint's example:  "https://%NETWORK_NAME%.infura.io/v3/%PROJECT_ID%".
4. Then you can deploy or import the contract.

Answer (score 0):

you can not filter events with infura, but it is possible with web3, infura is RPC provider, follow this steps to interact with the contract:

1- create your API key with RPC provider (here is infura), user same network as your deployment network.(I recommend to user websocket in infura)

2-put your API key in .env and your network configuration in your network config(in truffle uncomment network in truffle-config.js)

3-read [this question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/17117/web3-js-filter-events) about web3 event filtering